# 'layers' in html, transparent part

Tags: html, css, layer, css-shapes

I want this: http://gyazo.com/0fe69e349ed5cd4e72a08ed8e60af5d4 
But I can't manage to achieve it.

I can **not** change the image.
I have used an image as a mask, but that gives me this: http://gyazo.com/b69e840d095212bce422252cec081fe9 
Is there a way to make the side parts white aswell?

My code:

```
#section1{
    height:275px;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url('/img/paral1.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 916px;
}
.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:180px;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.mask{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url('/img/section1.png');
    height:100px;
    width:1080px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

edit: JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/31kxqmLt/ 
JSfiddle in fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/31kxqmLt/embedded/result/ 
edit edit: The mask must have a width of 1080px and the rest of the space should be white.

Comment: provide your html as well

Comment: or fiddle will be good

Comment: Something [like this example](http://jsbin.com/felah/1/edit) ? There is an optical illusion at smaller widths, it looks off-centre, but it's not!

Comment: misterManSam, the center part should be 1080px, and the left-right white parts should fill the rest of the page,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Js fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/31kxqmLt/5/)

full screen

[**Js fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/31kxqmLt/5/embedded/result/)

edited the mask image

set mask `width` to `100%` so that it fits in all the resolutions

```
.mask{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url('http://s29.postimg.org/5g7z03ypz/image.png') no-repeat bottom;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

for smaller resolution `min-width 300`

```
#section1{
    max-height:200px;
    min-height:30%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/31kxqmLt/6/)

Comment: The mask must have a width of 1080px and the rest of the space should be white.

Comment: changes made as required

Comment: How about this to make it responsive, with less markup and an img tag for SEO? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/31kxqmLt/6/

Answer (score 3):

I made this Html/css example of the shape you are trying to make.

It uses background image, pseudo elements and skewX  to give the transparent cut out effect on bottom left and bottom right. It also is responsive :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ncgwu4n1/)**

output :

[image: image with transparent mask]

```css
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:30%;
    position:relative;
}
.wrap:before {
    content:'';
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ug3M32a.jpg);
    background-size:100% auto;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    height:50%;
}
.b{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:50%; height:50%;
}
.l{
    left:5%;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3%;
}
.r{
    right:5%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom-right-radius:3%;
}
.l:before, .r:before{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background-size: 200%;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ug3M32a.jpg);
}
.l:before{
    background-position: 10% -100%;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
.r:before{
    background-position: 90% -100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
}
body {
    padding:20px 10%;
    background-image : url(http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="b l"></div>
    <div class="b r"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nicely done, quite a bit of work, good use of pseudo-elements.

Comment: @misterManSam I can't use that as an answer because it is not possible to display an image in the background of the grey shape (images would be skewed like the pseudo element) that is why I need to use more divs.

Comment: @web-tiki - oh yeah! Oh well, still pretty neat.